# Align div inline

Tags: css, html

How to make the second div inline to the first div.I need the flash swf to appear next to the tds

```
<html>

<div style="display: inline">
<table style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;">
    <tr>
                <td width ="20%">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%">
                    1.Can you view the image?
                </td>
                <td width="20%">
                    1.Can you upload the image?
                </td>

        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
            <div style="display: inline;">
                <object width="100" height="100">
                <embed src="image_tr.swf" width="250" height="250">
                </embed>
                </object>
            </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "inline to the first div"?

Comment: _20%_ + _20%_ + _20%_ != _100%_ and since you're using `tables` why don't you put your swf in another `td` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define the width of both divs and float them left and right

```
div1 {
 float:left;
//define the width
}
div2{
float:right;
//define the width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, note that display is not an inherited property, therefore if you simply specify display:inline for the table as well, it will be okay.